# Android: Does OOM priority apply for entire process or single Service?

Tags: android

Say that I have 2 services hosted in 1 process. 1 service is a foreground service (e.g. bound by a foreground UI, or display a persistent icon), while the other service is not foreground. According to docs, the foreground service has much higher priority and should almost never be killed. When memory gets low, can Android kill the non-foreground service, or does the process inherit the foreground priority and protect both services?

Answer (score 1):

Android does not kill services. It kills processes. The foreground service elevates the priority of the process.

Note that this means that having a foreground service needs to be something transient (e.g., foreground while you are downloading the movie the user purchased) or something controllable by the user (e.g., foreground while the music player is playing).